# "supportsHighlight" setting ignored in capabilities.json, custom visual still receives filtered data

Tags: powerbi

In capabilities.json, I added the code below, as per the docs:

`"supportsHighlight": true`

However, the custom visual is still receiving pre-filtered data, regardless of the interaction setting between visuals, and there is no "highlights" property anywhere in the data view object or any of its children objects.

I've tried API 1.5 and 1.6.

Is this feature broken at the moment?
Or is there a new way of declaring support for highlighting and the docs are lagging?
Or am I missing something really obvious and need to get new glasses?

How do I request highlighting in custom visuals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation does not mention it but it seems one has to install the [interactivity utils](https://github.com/microsoft/powerbi-visuals-utils-interactivityutils). Once installed and the `supportsHighlight` capability is set the extra data does appear in the `values`.